# Cannot resize application started at boot

Tags: startup-applications, 23.10

I have added Spotify and Signals applications to the startup programs through the "Startup Application Preferences".

They do start but those windows cannot be resized with the mouse by dragging the bottom right corner of the window. If I start them normally they can be resized. If I right click the window context menu and choose resize them I can also resize the window. Once I'm done resizing I still can't resize using the bottom right corner.

[image: Can't resize]

I'm using Ubuntu 23.10. What can be the reason for this? How do I fix it?